# Determine if the derivative $f'(0;a)$ exists for every vector $a$ and compute it's value in terms of the components of $a$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) = \dfrac {xy^3}{x^3 + y^6 }$ if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and define $f(0,0)=0$

Determine if the derivative $f'(0;a)$ exists for every vector $a$ and compute it's value in terms of the components of $a$.

**Attempt:**

$D_1f(0,0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \dfrac {h.0}{h^3}=0$.

Similarly : $D_2f(0,0) =0 \implies \nabla f(0) = 0 \widehat i + 0 \widehat j$.

Hence, if $a = (a_1,a_2), f~'(0;a) =  \nabla f(0). a = 0$

That means, the directional derivative along any direction is $0$?

Could someone please advise.

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Apostol, we shall define the directional derivative:
$$
f'(\mathbf{a};\mathbf{y}) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(\mathbf{a} + h\mathbf{y}) - f(\mathbf{a})}{h}
$$
where $\mathbf{y}$ is the vector along which we are deriving, and $\mathbf{a}$ is the point about which we are taking the derivative (boldface indicates a vector quantity). In terms of the problem you posted, $\mathbf{a} = (0,0)$ and $\mathbf{y} = (a_{1},a_{2})$. It is just a matter of subbing in these numbers. (Apologies for the confusing notation, but I am trying to follow the one used in the textbook. Just be careful that $\mathbf{a}$ is not $(a_{1},a_{2})$ here, even though that would be nice.) We find:
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(\mathbf{a} + h\mathbf{y}) - f(\mathbf{a})}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f((0,0) + h(a_{1},a_{2})) - f(\mathbf{0})}{h}
$$
We already know $f(0,0)$, so we can simplify a bit:
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f((0,0) + h(a_{1},a_{2})) - f(\mathbf{0})}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h*a_{1},h*a_{2}))}{h}
$$
$$
= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h^{4}a_{1}a_{2}^{3}}{h*(h^{3}a_{1}^{3} + h^{6}a_{2}^{6})}
$$
Now we can factor out and cancel off the $h$'s (haven't yet taken the limit) and we arrive at:
$$
=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{a_{1}a_{2}^{3}}{a_{1}^{3} + h^{3}a_{2}^{6}}
$$
Taking the limit zaps the term containing $h$ in the denominator and you can cancel a bit off to find your value of the derivative:
$$
f'(\mathbf{0};\mathbf{a}) = \frac{a_{2}^{3}}{a_{1}^{2}}
$$
Since we were able to find it in this fashion and didn't come across any discontinuities or undefined points, we shall say that it clearly exists.

Comment: My textbook Apostol says that the directional derivative exists at $0$ along each vector $a = (a_1,a_2)$ and is $a_2^3/a_1^2$ if $a_1 \ne 0$ and $0$ if $a_1=0$

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question. I'll refine my answer to mean the directional derivative.

Comment: Ok, I shall wait for your answer :)

Comment: @Wanderer, please see the new answer. Thanks for your patience. :)

Comment: @AGPeddle Does the strategy you used in your answer work in general? I applied it in [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1232197/93114) that I asked, in addition to another more complicated strategy, but I'm not sure if I applied it correctly.

Comment: @Michael, yes, this method applies in general.